# Modifying an array in Swift 2

Tags: swift2

```
shoppingList[4...6] = ["Bananas", "Oranges"]
```

Don't use subscript syntax to append a new item to an array.

But I realize append one or more new items to array with ranges successed. For example:

```
var shoppingList : Array<String> = ["Bread", "Milk", "Blackingbar", "Chian", "baba", "Oppo", "Xiaomi"]
shoppingList[4...6] = ["Bananas", "Oranges", "Huewei", "5", "6"]

for obj in shoppingList {
    print(obj)
}
```

Why we have recommeded "don't use it" ????

Answer (score 0):

The precise quote from the documentation is

> You can’t use subscript syntax to append a new item to the end of an
>   array.

Your code example replaces three items at index 4 - 6 with five other items simultaneously which is something different. As far as the subscripted range is not out of bounds the operation succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you would want to make 5 items replace the last 3 but if you need to do it, you could do this:

```
var shoppingList : Array<String> = ["Bread", "Milk", "Blackingbar", "Chian", "baba", "Oppo", "Xiaomi"]
shoppingList = shoppingList[0..<4] + ["Bananas", "Oranges", "Huewei", "5", "6"]
```